# Adding a post-commit/checkin hook to Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm trying to implement Continous Integration with Jenkins, TFS plugin - http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin .

My problem is triggering builds, what I want to do is somehow add a post-commit/checkin hook to Team Foundation Server, so far don't have any idea how to do this, is it even possible?

Don't want to use a trigger by Schedule.

Comment: Clarify your question: what's the relationship between Jenkins and TFS?

Comment: @GiulioVian i'm using this plugin in jenkins http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin - hope I understood correctly

Comment: @Stefan: did you ever have any luck with a TFS post-commit trigger? I'm thinking it may be possible to have a checkin alert, and customize the alert sent to Jenkins to trigger builds: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552337(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a post commit hook, what you want to do is listen for check in events.

1. Client side - write a small utility that listens for checkin events. Effectively it's a small listener app and you set up TFS to send notifications to it using the bissubscribe tool. It's a little old, but [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx) should give you a starting point.
2. Server side - write a custom event handler. The basic idea is shown [in this blog post](http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/), just be aware that changes to your event handler will cause the TFS app pool to recycle.

Comment: bad link for Client Side events